# Implementing Validation in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

Trying to validate my Phone Number so no one can input random letters inside the input box. I do have the unobtrusive and validate scripts. So far I have tried a few things inside my Model,

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?:(?:\(?(?:00|\+)([1-4]\d\d|[1-9]\d?)\)?)?[\-\.\ \\\/]?)?((?:\(?\d{1,}\)?[\-\.\ \\\/]?){0,})(?:[\-\.\ \\\/]?(?:#|ext\.?|extension|x)[\-\.\ \\\/]?(\d+))?$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid Phone number")]
[Display(Name = "Phone")]
public string SMSPhoneNumber;
```

or

```
[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
public string SMSPhoneNumber;
```

This is my View

```
<form role="form" action="#">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label"><b>Phone Number</b></label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SMSPhoneNumber, new {@class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Phone Number", @id = "phoneNumber", Name = "phoneNumber", data_val_required = "Please enter a phone number"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SMSPhoneNumber, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>  
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn dark btn-outline"> Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" id="" class="btn green" onclick="javascript: updateDatabase();">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is my controller

```
[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult UpdatePhoneNumber(string phoneNumber)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        return View();
    }
}
```

The validation is still not working, what could be the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your do not get client side validation is that you have changed the `name` attribute by using `new { Name = "phoneNumber" }` and you have not created a validation message placeholder for `phoneNumber` (just one for `SMSPhoneNumber`).

Under no circumstances should you ever change the `name` attribute. Nor should you be adding `data-val-*` attributes (and its not clear why your changing the `id` attribute). The `HtmlHelper` methods will always generate the correct html for model binding and validation when used correctly.

The reason you do not get any server side validation is that your not binding to your model, just to a `string`.

Change the view code to

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SMSPhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter Phone Number" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SMSPhoneNumber, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

and change the POST method to receive your model (assuming its say `public class Company`), then

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdatePhoneNumber(Company model)
```

Comment: Note also you have `onclick="javascript: updateDatabase();` which suggest you might be using ajax to submit, it which case you may not get client side validation unless that function is also implemented correctly by checking `.valid()` before posting to the controller.

Comment: Suggest you edit your question to include that as well so I can review and correct if necessary

Comment: Edited, I have the page doing exactly what i want, only issue here is the validation portion of it all.

Comment: Have your not read my answer? It explains exactly why you do not get either client side or server side validation (and I'll edit shortly to explain the problems with your ajax call). But the fact your have `if (ModelState.IsValid) { return View(); }` makes no sense with your ajax code. What are you expecting to happen here and what is `$('#smsPhoneNumberBody').html(data.result);` actually doing (i.e. what is being updated if `ModelState` is valid)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159823/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-draklin).